# socket.io client always closing

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket.io, python-socketio

hey i tried making this connection work... i first installed the updated version of python-socketio[client]==5.7.1 but apparently this version supports EIO=4 and the socket.io client i'm trying to open is EIO=3.. so i had to uninstall it and install an old version python-socketio==4.6.1 . after that i tried running this code

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client(ssl_verify=False,logger=True,engineio_logger=True)

@sio.event
def connect():
    print("Connected!")
    sio.emit("authorization",{"session":"2ot3i7..................3h","isDemo":1})

@sio.event
def connect_error(data):
    print("The connection failed!\n\n" + data)

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print("Disconnected!")


@sio.on('*')
def catch_all(event,data):
    pass



@sio.on('handshake')
def on_message(data):
    print('Handshake',data)
    sio.emit("instruments/update",{"asset":"GBPUSD","period":60})
    sio.emit("indicator/list")
    sio.emit("drawing/load")
    sio.emit("pending/list")
    sio.emit("chart_notification/get")
    sio.emit("depth/follow","GBPUSD")
    sio.emit("tick")
    sio.emit("settings/store",{"chartId":"graph","settings":{"chartId":"graph","chartType":2,"currentExpirationTime":0,"isFastOption":False,"isFastAmountOption":False,"isIndicatorsMinimized":False,"isIndicatorsShowing":True,"isShortBetElement":False,"chartPeriod":4,"currentAsset":{"symbol":"GBPUSD"},"dealValue":1000,"dealPercentValue":1,"isVisible":True,"timePeriod":60,"gridOpacity":8,"isAutoScrolling":1,"isOneClickTrade":True,"upColor":"#0FAF59","downColor":"#FF6251"}})
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    sio.connect('https://ws.quotex.io/socket.io/', transports=['websocket'])
    sio.wait()
```

and here is what came back...

```
Attempting WebSocket connection to wss://ws.quotex.io/socket.io/?transport=websocket&EIO=3
    WebSocket connection accepted with {'sid': '5AeKOf4oS0U-pHnaB1-2', 'upgrades': [], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 5000}
    Engine.IO connection established
    Sending packet PING data None
    Received packet MESSAGE data 0
    Received packet MESSAGE data 1
    Namespace / is connected
    Connected!
    Emitting event "authorization" [/]
    Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["authorization",{"session":"2ot......................3h","isDemo":1}]
    Disconnected!
    Received packet NOOP data None
    WebSocket connection was closed, aborting
    Waiting for write loop task to end
    Exiting write loop task
    Waiting for ping loop task to end
    PONG response has not been received, aborting
    Exiting ping task
    Engine.IO connection dropped
    Connection failed, new attempt in 1.41 seconds
    Exiting read loop task
    Attempting WebSocket connection to wss://ws.quotex.io/socket.io/?transport=websocket&EIO=3
    WebSocket connection accepted with {'sid': 'sQvjGss3KsxnBzQ2B2gI', 'upgrades': [], 'pingInterval': 25000, 'pingTimeout': 5000}
    Engine.IO connection established
    Sending packet PING data None
    Reconnection successful
    Received packet MESSAGE data 0
    Namespace / is connected
    Received packet MESSAGE data 1
    Connected!
    Emitting event "authorization" [/]
    Received packet NOOP data None
    Sending packet MESSAGE data 2["authorization",{"session":"2ot.......................3h","isDemo":1}]
    WebSocket connection was closed, aborting
    Waiting for write loop task to end
    Exiting write loop task
    Waiting for ping loop task to end
    PONG response has not been received, aborting
    Exiting ping task
    Engine.IO connection dropped
    Disconnected!
    Disconnected!
    Connection failed, new attempt in 0.90 seconds
    Exiting read loop task
```

i had to kill the terminal cause it was trying to reconnect

please if you have any questions to make my explanations clear you can comment and i'll answer
thank you if you can give an advice